# How to use curl command to get manifest v2 schema version 2

Tags: curl, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $BEARER" \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.image.manifest.v2+json" \
     https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/$NAME/manifests/sha256:3eb57a4024e69d05ace49be70ab9d13610cfe611a0191c7edc26f5a2b675e7b1
```

Above is the command I use. I've already set the Accept field to be **schema version 2** manifest media type in the header but still it returns me manifest with **schema version 1**

Comment: What does this line ` https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/$NAME/manifests/sha256:3eb57a4024e69d05ace49be70ab9d13610cfe611a0191c7edc26f5a2b675e7b1` refer to? How is it derived?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the Accept type for a v2 schema is `"application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"` according to the docker registry code, see:

https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/f4b6fc8d681c42137b7d2bb544b087462bc34d47/manifest/schema2/manifest.go#L15